# Copernican Principle defended using Algorithmic Information Theory?

Tags: time, determinism, probability

Imagine a chronologically-ordered list of all the n humans who will ever live. I am already assuming that time is linear rather than say a branching structure.

Can the Copernican Principle be defended using Algorithmic Information Theory?

Most humans require a minimal-length computer program of roughly log_2( n ) bits to specify their position r in the list (using the number n as input). This leads to a uniform conditional probability distribution P( r | n ) = 1 / n and hence the Doomsday argument. If you assume your position can be specified more easily then you are making the unwarranted assumption that your position is special.

Is this correct?

**Background**

The Copernican principle is the assumption that the observer is not special amongst a group of observers.

The Doomsday Argument (DA) is an application of the Copernican Principle that purports to allow us to estimate the total number of humans who will ever be born. A version of the DA goes like this:

Imagine a chronological list of all the n humans who will ever be born (assumes a linear timeline).

If we take an algorithmic information theory view then the majority of humans require a program of length log_2(n) bits to specify their position r in the list (assuming the program is given the number n as input). This leads to a uniform prior probability density function for their fractional position f = r / n.

By change of variables from f to n we can derive the Doomsday Argument result that the posterior probability density function for n is r / n^2.

But I personally believe that the Doomsday Argument fails because I believe in the Many-Worlds Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics which implies a branching structure to time.

Comment: If you are going to refer to something like "the Copernican Principle" or "the Doomsday" argument, please provide at least a brief description and if possible, a citation. Not everyone has been reading the same things you have been reading in the last few months.

Comment: What do you mean by "chronological list?" Can you give an example of how to specify in log_2(n) bits the position of an entry in this list? Also, please give an example of how this can work given *ONLY* n as input. You mention a probability density function, but not what it is the probability of.  Your mention of quantum mechanics seems to be a complete non-sequitur since nothing previous has had any significant connection to quantum mechanics. The many worlds interpretation does not imply a branching structure to time. Plus what is your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

First of all log_2(n) isn't the length of the program but the big O notation or complexity of the program. So the amount of operations required for that program scales with log_2(n). That doesn't mean that you can't write it as an algorithm with fixed size.

Also you're dealing with 2 different small n here. Like on the one hand you argue that let's call it big N is the number of people who WILL ever live. But in order to determine your position on the list you only need to know the number of people who have ever lived before you (assuming you're sorted by birth not some other random date in time) whoever comes after you doesn't matter for your position on the list.

And it also makes the assumption that you've get some feedback. Like the argument is that you take the number n of all humans that have ever lived, pick the middle of that number and ask if your number is bigger or smaller, then you do the same for the middle between the middle and either 0 or n and so on. That is what lead to the log_2(n) function because you half the number of options with every step.

However that only works for a known n while the Doomsday argument assumes to know n and doesn't at the same time?

Also what about looking at that not from the abstract but as a concrete problem. Like you know the start point and you can model growth of the human population, giving you an educated guess, but does not rely on the unwarranted assumption that you are special. And then you do your bigger smaller game. Which stills scales with log_2() but maybe you manage to start from sqrt(n) or less.

**Update:**
Once again the log_2(n) has absolutely nothing to do with the length of the program or it's bit size. It denotes how the number of operations required to get your position scales with the total number. The idea is a simple number guessing game. You select a number between 0 and 1024 and I try to guess it and after each guess you tell me higher, lower or congratulation. Now if I pick the middle as the demarcation line then 1/2 of the options are gone. In the next step I'd take the middle of what's left and so on. So it's obvious that after at most 10 guesses I have your number because there's only 1 number left, regardless of what number you've picked. You know, because 10 guesses means 2¹⁰ = 1024 possible options or conversely log_2(1024) = 10. Edit: Or maybe instead of numbers and higher/lower think of finding a book in a library. You know it's title and you know that the books are ordered alphabetically, you don't know how many A's, B's and so on there are but they are all neatly lined up so that you can pick the middle and know whether you're book is to the left or the right of it, but don't know where exactly it is despite knowing the title.

So this big O notation tells you how the number of guesses scales with the number of options. Btw log_2 is pretty awesome if you'd compare it with idk asking "Is that your number?" for every possible number which would be O(n). Just compare 10 for log_2 to 1024 for n, or 50 for log_2 and 1,125,899,906,842,624. It has nothing to do with the length or bit size of the program which could be the same for any n, it's just about how many operations or guesses are performed.

And how does that lead to a uniform distribution? Like the latter samples would have a much harder time to figure out their position because their n would be bigger. Assuming that n denotes the people that HAVE LIVED BEFORE as the number of people who WILL EVER LIVE is an unknown quantity and therefore unsuitable for this calculation.

And this log_2 approach requires that the people are sorted, so that you can tell if it's higher or lower. If they are indeed sampled at random with a uniform probability distribution then none of that would work and you're back with a complexity of O(n). So how if at all are these things even related to each other?

So in order for all to have the same log_2(n) complexity, n would need to denote the final number of how many humans would ever exist. Which a) would not mean that they are equally easy to guess because powers of 2 would be easier to guess than powers of 2+-1. And b) At that point that is basically circular reasoning because you assume that number is fixed to then come up with the conclusion that this number is fixed...

Like if you'd sample 2 more people 1 a billions of positions before and 1 a trillion of positions after you and apply the same argument their end number would be vastly larger or smaller or you'd have picked the same number for no particular reason at which point it should be obvious that the conclusion was used as premise.

Not to mention that any derivation of time estimates seems majorly sketchy given that none of that probability actually deals with time. Like if there a demon terminating the universe when the number of humans reaches more than 200 billion in total, then you're position now would indeed be special and not random as you're closer to that edge than people before and not as close as people after you. So you'd know you're position and wouldn't have to guess it.

So the Doomsday argument tells you exactly nothing about the doomsday. Apparently it only tells you that you can't derive your actual status within a set by self-sampling:
https://anthropic-principle.com/q=anthropic_principle/doomsday_argument/

It works for groups but not for individuals, ... which is hardly new information

Comment: I’m just working with a chronological list of humans so the rate of population growth with time is factored out of the argument. The information theory approach is used to justify the uniform probability distribution for our position r conditional on knowing the total number of humans n. Using a so-called vague prior distribution for n, P(n) = 1/n, and the conditional probability for r, P(r|n)= 1/n, we can use Bayes’s theorem to derive the posterior probability distribution for n, P(n|r)= r / n^2.

Answer (score 1):

Our position and relation with *space* and *matter* are much easier to derive a Copernican principle about than humans as for one thing cosmology is a physical process that doesn’t change upon subjective knowledge. Cosmological facts are taken as objective. How we moralize space and matter distribution does not change our physical relation to them. Once we establish those objective facts (refuting heliocentrism and geocentrism, evidence for inflationary models, etc) they are set.

There’s little reason to think we can establish a Copernican principle in the same way for such a system as human population. We aware humans partly direct the process. Our own knowledge, beliefs, and desires influence the outcome and our relation to the total. We can continually add bias like being the first generation to have male contraceptives, adopt antinatalism in response to another cultural move, learn how quickly human population will outpace our resources, etc. These all directly influence the population totals and our relation to them. We cannot possibly be average ever with this kind of relationship. Algorithmic information theory doesn’t solve this.